# To specify Family id as random effect in GLMM or lme

Tags: r

I am trying to fit generalized linear mixed model in R. I have big pedigree and genotype data. I tried this:

```
m1 <- lmer(Final_sx~(1 | ID)+cohort2+cohort3+cohort4+sex,
           data=solar_new_phen,family=poisson)
```

And it gave me message:

> Number of levels of a grouping factor for the random effects is
>   *equal* to n, the number of observations

I have seen in most of tutorials people are using ID as clustering variable. In kinship package as well in lmekin function it is like this:

```
rand.eff=formula(paste("~1|",sub.ID))
fit <- try(lmekin(fixed=fix.eff,data=x,random = rand.eff,varlist=list(kmat)))
```

Should I be using individual id or family id as random effect? I am confused. I have pedigrees and I think I should be using Family ID as clustering variable. It would be great if someone can guide me with little explanation about random effects.

Comment: [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18563/3601) over on Cross Validated is related and may help.

Comment: You should probably be using "family id" for the random effect part of the formula, if you're trying to estimate a separate variance component for families. This would make sense if you expected your response to be correlated within families, for example (which it probably would be). You could (additionally) include an individual-level random effect possibly correlated with the family-level random effect IF you had multiple observations per individual. It does not appear you do. I would reformat your question and ask on stats.stackexchange.com if your question is more statistical in nature.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have probably only one row by ID ! For this, you need many obs for 1 ID